# Multiple Redis-Lua calls for same script

Tags: redis, lua, eval

I have loaded a script on lua server and multiple clients can execute the script with SHA generated from loading. I know that a lua script execution is atomic in Redis. But if multiple clients executes same lua script at same time, will each EVALSHA call still be atomic or one client could interrupt in between call of another client? And will this execution be on FCFS basis at Redis?

Answer (score 3):

> if multiple clients executes same lua script at same time, will each EVALSHA call still be atomic?

Yes.

> if multiple clients executes same lua script at same time, could one client could interrupt in between call of another client?

No.

Note: It can be interrupted via [SCRIPT KILL](https://redis.io/commands/script-kill) command.

> will this execution be on FCFS basis at Redis?

Yes.